# How to get rid of annoying Non-secure Jabber Login popup?

Tags: macos, security, messages, google, jabber

My Messages app out-of-blue started to complain that my GTalk credentials are being sent in non-secured manner.

> Your name and password will be sent in a way that is not secure.
>
> Do you still wish to connect to this server?

[image: Non-secure Jabber Login - Your name and password will be sent in a way that is not secure.]

This was working all the time and I didn't change anything (including my network).

**How do I fix it?**

I've checked my Server Settings for GTalk account, but it seems my 'Use SSL' is greyed out, so I can't enable it.

[image: Messages - Server Settings]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you've to just turn on the 'Use SSL' option (*Preferences->Accounts->Google->Server Settings*).

It's greyed out, because the option 'Automatically find server and port' is enabled. If the option is greyed as well, disable temporary the account then disable the option, then set the manual settings or try to click on 'Use Default Settings' option. You can use either 5222, 5223 or 443.

Answer (score 1):

I tried various combinations of checking and unchecking SSL, Automatically finding server, etc., and none of these interventions worked.

What worked for me was to go to Internet Accounts under System Preferences, and deleting my Google account (by highlighting Google and clicking on the "–" box) and then just adding it back in again by clicking on the "+" box and re-entering my Google User ID and Password. It just took a few seconds to do this and it fixed the problem.

Hope this might help others.

Answer (score 1):

I had this popup appearing about every 2 minutes and driving me crazy.  So go to **Messages** → **Preferences** → **Google** and uncheck every box. This will close the jabber thing in messages and then no more pop-ups.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I could resolve this was to delete the account and then add it back. This was from an account I had for years when google seemed to use jabber. Now it is GTalk which seems to be secure.

Comment: thank you for the advise. I had this issue for a month and it was very annoying. So, I've deleted and reinstalled my gmail accounts and it did the trick!